# Change background-image on hover, but also on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The background image is an image of an office. The background image will have a few `<a>` tags where the person can click. For example: there is an `<a>` tag on a computer that's on the desk. Taking this example, I want to do the following:

- Hovering **on** the `<a>` tag that is over the computer, will load in a picture of the same office, however, the computer has been outlined with a white line in photoshop (**Lets say: `img/bureau2`**). Indicating that it is interactable. Hovering **away** from this will return it to the original picture which you see when you enter site (**`img/bureau1`**)
- You can also click on the `<a>` tag. This will open up another image (**`img/bureau3`**).

So far I managed to get the change on `hover` and `click` to work. Issue is, hovering **away** from the `<a>` tag will cancle the `click`.

This is what I have so far, how can I tackle this issue?

```js
$(".computerHover").hover(function() {

    $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'img/bureau2.png');

  },
  function() {

    $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'img/bureau.png');

  });


$(".computerHover").click(function() {

  $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'img/bureau3.png');

});
```

```css
#pagina2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#backgroundImage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
}

.computerHover {
  width: 105px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 28vw;
  top: 40vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagina2">
  <div id="pagina2Background">

    <img id="backgroundImage" src="img/bureau.png">

    <div class="computer">
      <a class="computerHover"></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been looking into this, but I can't understand your plan for the other hyperlinks. You're specifically targeting `.computerHover` but what about the others? For example how with they be positioned? However you do this will need to be dynamic if you want to show images for the other links.

Comment: @EternalHour my bad. Those other links (I think you are referring to brilHover and bordHover) are so far not yet added.

They will do basically the same the as the Computer-example which I gave above, but then load a background image of the office with that specific item lit-up

Comment: Yeah but what I'm saying is that if you plan on doing the same thing with them you need to include it in your question because that needs to be part of the solution.

Comment: @EternalHour My bad. I will delete it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me, what you are trying to do, is an [image map](http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap/). But for the sake of your question, I will focus on one particular link.

The reason the click generated image disappears when you move the mouse, is because it is still bound to the previous hover event. The `hover` method is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. In order to circumvent that, you need to unbind that event handler.

EDIT:
I reworked my answer to more closely resemble the code in your question. In order to "reset" the image, I would suggest using a link that the user can click to make it less confusing for them.

```js
function switchImage() {
$(".computerHover").hover(function() {
$("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Computer');
  },
  function() {
$("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Office');
  });
}

// attach the hover events when page loads
switchImage();

$(".computerHover").on("click", function() {
$(this).off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=New Background');
});

// reattach hover handlers and set image back to default
$(".reset").on("click", function() {
switchImage();
  $("#backgroundImage").attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Office');
});
```

```css
#pagina2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#backgroundImage {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
  display: block;
}

.computerHover {
  width: 105px;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 28vw;
  top: 40vh;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagina2">
  <div id="pagina2Background">
<a class="reset">Start Over</a>
<img id="backgroundImage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300.png?text=Office">

<div class="computer">
  <a class="computerHover">Computer</a>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly the effect that I am trying to do!

I indeed forgot to mention things in regards to the third image.

My idea was to probably re-click on the same `<a>` (in this instance, the computer one) tag so you go back to the original/first image where you can do the selection. It basically should loop i guess? where i can hover on it, click on it to open another image, click on the computer again to close, and be able to hover and click on it again. if that makes sense. Just like in a game where you can select something, go back, but be able to reselect it too.

Comment: If this makes it more clear: you click on it, open image 3 and unbind the hover as you dks. Click on it again, you go back to the first/selection image and re-bind the hover stuff so it works indefinitely

Comment: @vorkot1 I updated the answer, should work for you and can modify as needed.

Comment: Appreciated so much!

I am sorry if this is not allowed to ask. But i wondered if you  might have a Discord or something? I would like to ask you a few more small questions if that's alright.

Comment: @vorkot1 We can chat here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/103315/eternalhour?tab=general

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you'll need to keep some sort of state that indicates that the user clicked instead of just hover. In the click handler you could add a class or data-* to `#backgroundImage` element that you later check when you un-hover.

Example [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-moore-we066).

Comment: If i understand correctly, with the "add class" part: Would I need to create a class in CSS. for instance `.computerClicked`. Add the image in there, and then use `addClass` in the click function (instead of `attr`)? or am i going the wrong way?

Comment: By add class I mean to add a class to the img element. Check this example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_add_class
When you click 'Try it', it adds a class to the div.

Comment: What would the class need to contain (the other img? Other stuff?). Sorry, im still very bad with all of this

Comment: Don't worry. We all start there. I hope this can give you and idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-moore-we066. When you hover and un-hover the image change. When you click and un-hover the image stay the way it is. Links are at the bottom.